# Batch file to set dns address only if adapter is currently set to statically assigned

Tags: batch-file, static, dhcp

First post, noob at coding.  I'm looking for a batch file to set dns servers if the adapter dhcp enabled setting is set to No.  I actually have this working but its limited. Currently if it sees any adapter with dhcp enabled as no then it sets the dns server on all nics.  I need it to also check to see if dhcp is not enabled and the nic is not the loopback adapter.  Something like if dhcp enabled = no and ip address <> 127.0.0.1 then set the dns server addresses.

Heres what I currently have...

```
@echo off
SET _DHCP=Maybe
For /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh interface ip show addresses ^|FIND "DHCP Enabled"') DO SET _DHCP=%%a
IF "%_DHCP%"=="No" Then

 @echo off
 set dnsserver=192.168.25.200
 set dnsserver2=192.168.25.201
 for /f "tokens=1,2,3*" %%i in ('netsh interface show interface') do (
 if %%i EQU Enabled (
 rem echo change "%%l" : %dnsserver%
 netsh interface ipv4 set dnsserver name="%%l" static %dnsserver% both
 netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver name="%%l" %dnsserver2% index=2
 )
)
```

If I could just figure out how to pull in the IP Address at the same time as the dhcp status I think it would give me what I need.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's the adapter's name?, Or are you trying to set the `dns` for each one where `dhcp` is disabled?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As a noob in coding, go step by step: **1.** `netsh interface ip show addresses`: you probably get more interfaces; add `name=<string>`. **2**. Add `|FIND /I "DHCP Enabled"`: the `/I` switch is important as `FIND` is case sensitive by default. **3** embed it fo `For /f "tokens=2 delims=:"  … do ECHO set "_DHCP=%%a"`: you see a lot of spaces there; use rather `For /f "tokens=3" …`. **4.** `if /?` shows that there is no `then` keyword … Etc., etc. …

Comment: Correct trying to set dns for each interface where dhcp is disabled.  I don't know the adapter name since it could change from system to system. It does it for all  adapters right now but its because its seeing the loopback adapter as having dhcp disabled so then it executes the code.

Comment: Can you do a find on two different items at once? Like..For /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh interface ip show addresses ^|FIND "DHCP Enabled" "IP Address"')